# Windows Phone UWP : App getting crash while swipe, Pivot Control Without any exception

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I am using pivot control for swiping some number of articles(e.g:20) based on following XAML design

```
<Page
    x:Class="NAMESPACE.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:NAMESPACE"
    xmlns:ViewModels="using:NAMESPACE.ViewModels"
    xmlns:common="using:NAMESPACE.Classes"
    xmlns:stringBind="using:NAMESPACE.Classes"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:q42controls="using:Q42.WinRT.Controls"
    xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
    Background="Gray"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ViewModels:ArticleViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTest">
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
            <StackPanel Margin="-15 0 -15 0">
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="PlaceHolderImage" Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg"></Image>
                    <Image q42controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri="{Binding ImageURL}" Tag="{Binding ImageURL}" Tapped="ImageView"></Image>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Background="Black">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdatedDate}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 10 0 10" 
                               FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                               Foreground="#777"></TextBlock>
                    <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" Background="Black" Opacity="0.1">
                    </Border>
                    <RichTextBlock x:Name="HeadLine" local:Properties.Html="{Binding HeadLine}"  
                                               Margin="10 5 10 -5" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                               FontSize="{Binding HeadlineFontSize}" Foreground="White"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource HeadlineCommonFamiy}"
                                               Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo"
                                               IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"/>
                    <RichTextBlock local:Properties.Html="{Binding Abstract}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{Binding AbstractFontSize}"
                                   Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 5 10 10"
                                   Foreground="#999"
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource AbstractCommonFamily}"
                                   IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="descriptionSP" Background="Black">
                    <Image Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg" Width="300" Height="250"></Image>
                    <UI:AdControl
                        AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                        ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                        AdUnitId="10865270"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="250"
                        IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="5,-240,5,5"
                        Width="300"/>
                    <RichTextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" x:Name="richTextBlock" 
                                   local:Properties.Html="{Binding ArticleDetail}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="White"
                                   Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10,10,10,-20"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}">
                    </RichTextBlock>
                    <Image Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg" Width="300" Height="250"></Image>
                    <UI:AdControl
                        AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                        ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                        AdUnitId="10865270"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="250"
                        IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"                        
                        Margin="5,-220,5,5"
                        Width="300"/>
                    <WebView x:Name="criticWebView" Visibility="{Binding WebViewVisibility}" Height="300" 
                             Source="{Binding CriticReviewUrl}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Foreground="White" Background="Black">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton x:Uid="Share" Foreground="White" Click="Share_Click" Label="Share">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon Foreground="White" UriSource="/Assets/Share.png" Height="30" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Favorite" Foreground="White" Name="favIcon" Click="Favorite_Click" Label="Favorite" Margin="0,-2,0,0"></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Foreground="White" Name="Settings" Click="Settings_Click" Label="Settings" Margin="0,-2,0,0"></AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
    <Grid Background="Black" x:Name="grid">
        <Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid" Visibility="Visible">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="progressRing" IsActive="True" Foreground="#d03438" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="60"
                          Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 20 0 0"></ProgressRing>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="logoImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/Maalaimalar_logo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 5 0 0"></Image>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="swipeBetweenPages" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Pivot DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" x:Name="pivot" Margin="0,-45,0,0" 
                                 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTest}" 
                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
                </Pivot>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <Grid  Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black" Name="popUp">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Source="/Assets/Close_White.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="CloseImage"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0" Height="30"></Image>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll" ZoomMode="Enabled" Grid.Row="2">
                <Image x:Name="popUpImage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-50,0,0"></Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And below is the code behind to bind the data in to XAML

```
data = e.Parameter as Feed;
                feedList = data.Articles;

                localSettings.Values["ChildName"] = feedList[0].ChildName;

                for (int z = 0; z < feedList.Count; z++)
                {
                    string articleDetail = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(feedList[z].ArticleDetail);
                    articleDetail = articleDetail.Replace("<[^>]*>", Environment.NewLine);
                    articleDetail = articleDetail.Replace("<div><br /></div>", "<br /><br />");
                    feedList[z].ArticleDetail = articleDetail;

                    if (feedList[z].ChildName == "Review")
                    {
                        feedList[z].WebViewVisibility = "Visible";
                        feedList[z].CriticReviewUrl = feedList[z].CriticReviewUrl.Replace("Review", "CriticReviewMobile");
                        feedList[z].CriticReviewUrl = Constants.Constants.BaseUrl.CriticUrl + feedList[z].CriticReviewUrl;
                    }
                    else
                        feedList[z].WebViewVisibility = "Collapsed";
                }


                index = data.ListingIndex + 1;
                if (index > feedList.Count - 1)
                {
                    index = 0;
                }
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    index = feedList.Count;
                }
                List<Article> feedList1 = new List<Article>();
                feedList1.Add(feedList[index - 1]);
                int j = index;
                for (int i = 0; i < feedList.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (j >= feedList.Count)
                    {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    feedList1.Add(feedList[j]);
                    j++;
                }
                feedList = feedList1;
                var viewModel = pivot.DataContext as ArticleViewModel;
                viewModel.BindListToView(feedList);

                LoadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                swipeBetweenPages.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

While Swipe, the app gets crash after 5 or less swipe with out any exception. I have included hockey app into my app, but the crash is not handled in the crash report also.

Please help me to resolve the issue..

Comment: Hello. Did you tried to remove the ScrollViewer around the Pivot ?

Comment: No.. I didn't try by removing the Scroll Viewer around Pivot

Comment: Can you try it please :) ?

Comment: I too have the same issue, any solution ?